# hexadecimal to unique identifier

Tags: format, hex, stata

I have a panel data set where each user is identified by a unique 16-digit hexadecimal userid. When I import this into Stata the userid turns red as Stata does not recognize this format. How can I convert this hexadecimal into a unique numeric identifier that Stata can recognize so that I can do further analysis with the panel?

Comment: Show us a data example and the exact code you used to import. You're expecting coding support without showing us any code.

Answer (score 0):

You should really provide a [minimal working example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

I guess you are looking for something like [this](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/)?

An example would be something like:

```
clear 
input oldid var1 var2
"abc" 1 20
"abc" 2 21
"abc" 4 25
"def" 5 23
"def" 5 21
"hij" 6 27
end

egen newid = group(oldid)
```

Comment: The last line is good technique for many problems but I see nothing here about 16 digit or hexadecimal identifiers. I am still unsure whether the OP meant "16 digit" or "hexadecimal" or indeed both; that remains a problem; but your answer is no answer as it considers neither. So, this is good advice, but doesn't answer the question.